# Does a longer SATA-II cable have an effect on the system's performance?

Tags: performance, sata, cable

I have a full tower case. I put my DVD-RW on top of the case. Therefore a regular cable won't reach it and I bought a longer cable (100 cm).

In the future, I will buy longer cables for my two hard disks too.

Does a longer SATA-II cable have an effect on the system's performance?

---

Thank you all.

I have google it and find out already...

http://www.ehow.com/facts_6869347_maximum-length-sata-cable.html

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read, most, if not all, mechanical drives don't reach the full saturation point of SATA II (although SSD drives are getting there, supposedly prompting the development of SATA 6Gps) so, at the max standard length (which you have) of 100cm, you probably won't see any issues so long as your cables meet the SATA standard.

Comment: Just like ethernet. . .

Answer (score 0):

A meter-long SATA cable?? AFAIK, the SATA standard has maximum recommended cable lengths (too long and there's signal degredation and performance loss), but I'm not sure what that precise length is. For some reason, 18" pops into mind.

Comment: According to [Seagate](https://www.seagate.com/support/kb/serial-ata-sata-data-cable-lengths-182453en/) the maximum length is "1 meter or 39.37 inches, [although] PCB traces from the cable connection to the host and drive controllers ASIC, adds length to the bus".